# Crawling limited number of pages

Tags: scrapy

I'am writing a spider for a forum. I am trying to to is to crawl recursively some pages of a section. So I set the rules below:

```
rules = (
    Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('&order=desc&page=\d'),restrict_xpaths=("//td[@class='navpage']/a"))
    ,callback='parse_items', follow= True),)
```

Is it possible to set a page limit so the spider could crawl a limited number of pages? For example to crawl from page 1 to page 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SgmlLinkExtractor`'s [`allow`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#sgmllinkextractor) parameter takes a regex. So you can modify your allow regex to look for any digit (`\d`) to look for only range `[1-8]` by doing:

```
SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('&order=desc&page=[1-8]'),restrict_xpaths=("//td[@class='navpage']/a"))
,callback='parse_items', follow= True),
```